How to force ESLint with flat config to respect rule discovered by tsconfig (useDefineForClassFields)
I'm looking way to make ESLint behave same way as rules check in tsconfig.json
The code:
export class SomePage  {
  private page: Page;
  commentButton = this.page.getByTestId('open-comments');

  constructor(private page: Page) {}
};

My tsconfig.json:
  {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "ESNext",
      "useDefineForClassFields": true, // Default value form ES2022, just for ref 
      "module": "CommonJS",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "baseUrl": ".",
    }
  }

The line with commentButton.
is highlighted because of error:
Property 'page' is used before its initialization.ts(2729)

And it is clearly discovered in VSCode:
https://i.imgur.com/s7volAD.png
But ESLint do not pickup this problem. Here is configuration eslint.config.mjs:
import pluginJs from '@eslint/js';
import globals from 'globals';
import tseslint from 'typescript-eslint';

export default [
  { files: ['**/*.ts'] },
  {
    languageOptions: {
      globals: globals.node,
    },
  },
  pluginJs.configs.recommended,
  ...tseslint.configs.recommended,
];

Finally this is ES2022 rule so why is not respected by ESLint?
Maybe importing tsconfig to ESLint config make sense?
Environment:
 $ npx tsc -v
 Version 5.6.3

package.json
{
  "name": "tests",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "npx eslint . -c ./tslint.config.mjs. --max-warnings=0"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@eslint/js": "^9.12.0",
    "@types/node": "^22.7.5",
    "eslint": "^9.12.0",
    "globals": "^15.11.0",
    "typescript-eslint": "^8.8.1"
  }
}


Your code cant be used to reproduce

It also does not recognize the issue with { parser )?

@avifen thanks for pointing out some errors. I corrected it. Anyway problem persist :D

...just speculating, but why would the eslint typescript plugin devs recreate a rule already checked by the compiler? Is it possible that they just don't intend for this to be caught in lint?

@JaredSmith good point. I wonder if it's possible to connect them somehow, as I want to verify this through static code analysis.

So what's happen is that you don't really let it check TS things, you just let it lint with rules that you give that can be checked while linting, but it can't transpile this way.
If you want it to actually perform checking of your code and not just lint, you need to make it tslinter, and give it parser option to understand what to parse:
export default tseslint.config(
    ...tseslint.configs.recommended,
    pluginJs.configs.recommended,
    {
        languageOptions: {
            globals: globals.node,
            parserOptions: {
                projectService: true,
                project: "./tsconfig.json",
                tsconfigRootDir: import.meta.url,
            },
        },
    }
);

In tsconfig.json add:
{
// Other configs you have
    "files": ["./eslint.config.mjs"]
}

Results:
  4:23  error  'page' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
  4:29  error  'Page' is not defined             no-undef


Thanks for explanation! How to use this config?

As you use eslint, its the same file name and all, just different.

Ok - I missed some important point. The configuration works itself. I wish to check errors form typescript like:
Property 'page' is used before its initialization.ts(2729)
I corrected code and added more context to question.

When I create config proposed by you with tsconfig from my question I get tslint.config.mjs was not found by the project service. Consider either including it in the tsconfig.json or including it in allowDefaultProject

Can you try including it in tsconfig?

Yep, added at the end of my tsconfig.json:   "include": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.mjs", "*.mjs", "*.ts"]

I updated question to list packages and versions also with tsc version

Updated answer with adjustment needed for tsconfig. I would be happy to hear why do you need it? what is the case?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
